# jQuery: Run function on element that is child of passed parameter

Tags: jquery

I have the following function:

```
function finishAnimation(section, obj, flow)
{
    var position = "";

    if (flow)
    {
        position = "-1000px"
    }

    obj.animate({
        left: '-1000px'
    }, 600, function () {
        jQuery(".correct-list").animate({
            top: '-375px'
        }, 300, function () {
            //over
        });
    });
}
```

What it does is animate an element with a class of .correct-list and the function is run like:

```
finishAnimation($("#whichqualifications"), $("#whichqualifications .blocks"), true);
```

The bit I'm stuck with is passing the section so that the .correct-list being animated is the one within the section. So how I prefix the section to the bit of code?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps (Please correct me if I'm wrong)

```
function finishAnimation(section, obj, flow)
{
    var position = "";

    if (flow)
    {
        position = "-1000px"
    }

    obj.animate({
        left: '-1000px'
    }, 600, function () {
        section.find(".correct-list").animate({
            top: '-375px'
        }, 300, function () {
            //over
        });
    });
}
```

The [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find) method searches within the descendants of all elements included in the jQuery object it was called on. It's interchangeable with `$(selector, context)`, as explained [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context).

Comment: Hi that doesn't work as it's not 'this' and instead needs to use the passed parameter 'section'

Comment: hi sorry. I changed that fairly quickly after posting the answer. you must have seen it before I edited it!

Answer (score 0):

Provide the element as the context for the jQuery call.  If it's inside the object, then use `obj` instead of `section`.

```
function finishAnimation(section, obj, flow)
{
    var position = "";

    if (flow)
    {
        position = "-1000px"
    }

    obj.animate({
        left: '-1000px'
    }, 600, function () {
        jQuery(".correct-list",section).animate({ // <-- note change
            top: '-375px'
        }, 300, function () {
            //over
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work but adding the .correct-list to the section passed and then just using the section in the method does work